# django/apache2 serving media isn't working on production

Tags: django, apache2, django-media

i'm running django mod_wsgi with apache2 on GCP VM instance and when i run it on DEBUG=False the static files work fine but media files is geting 404 when i check them while clearly the files are present on the server .
my conf is based on the following django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

```
#settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "media")
MEDIA_URL = os.environ.get("MEDIA_URL", "/media/")

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static")
STATIC_URL = os.environ.get("STATIC_URL", "/static/")

#apache2
Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/myshop/media/
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/myshop/static/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/myshop/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/myshop/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

tried restarting apache2 and even the server but didnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it was an https problem i needed to add the config to both virtualhost file port 80 and 443

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/myshop/media/
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/myshop/static/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/myshop/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/myshop/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/myshop/media/
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/myshop/static/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/myshop/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/myshop/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your alias is wrong...

```
#apache2
Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/myshop/media/
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/myshop/static/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/myshop/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

the alias has a backslash and your directory statement does not.

Comment: removing the backslash from the alias or adding one on the directory file doesnt solve the problem so i kept it similar to the docs

Comment: may be a permission issue then.   What happens when you navigate with debug turned on, what is the error message?

Comment: works fine with debug = True when i remove + static("/media/", document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) i get 404 not found in the console

Comment: the permision looks like that drwxrwxrwx   5 www-data     www-data       4096 Dec 21 13:18 media